# How to manipulate ntext type data in stored procedure of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-function

I was wondering how to manipulate ntext  datatype in stored procedure of SQL Server 2008.
We have a column of type ntext in a table. We have to fetch data from that column, parse the data, change and then store it back.
For all of the above task we have to use one or more than on stored procedure/function. So data passing between stored procedures are also involved.

Comment: There had better be a **good** reason not to have converted to `nvarchar(max)`, since `ntext` is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). Care to share the reason?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , I didnt check what nvarchar(max) was capable of. If it can hold the data as long as that of ntext then I can go in and change the data type of the columns to nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're in the position to change the schema, consider changing the data type from `ntext` to `nvarchar(max)`.  The later is new in SQL Server 2005, it's more efficient, and it works with string functions.

If you can't change the schema, convert the `ntext` to a local variable of type `nvarchar(max)`.  String functions do work with `nvarchar(max)`.  Example:

```
declare @txt nvarchar(max)
select @txt = NTextField from YourTable where id = @ID

... process @txt ...

update YourTable set NTextField = @txt where id = @ID
```

Comment: you mean nvarchar(max) can handle data longer than 8000 in length?
is there any max limit for nvarchar(max)?

Comment: [max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)  That's 2GB.

Comment: `(max)` was introduced in [2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939(v=SQL.90).aspx), not 2008.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I've edited the answer (as you could have :))